# Convertir páginas a pdf con dompdf en Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

Estoy tratando de generar un PDF con dompdf en Laravel 5.1 pero tengo un problema cuando carga el contenido html. Al parecer no termina de cargar por completo partes que agrego al contenido html desde Javascript haciendo uso de:

```
$('#contenido_tabla').append(insertar_tabla);
```

Cuando realizo un `return $view;` en mi controlador antes de generar el pdf, todo parece estar bien, carga el contenido correctamente.
El problema surge cuando hace el `loadHTML`. El contenido mencionado ya no aparece.
Tal vez estoy cometiendo algún error o quizá no es posible por algún factor, estoy atento a cualquier colaboración gracias de antemano

Este es parte de mi codigo en el controlador:

```
$datos = Datos::find($id);

$view =  view('pdf/informe_pdf', ['datos'=>$datos,'request'=>$request])->render();  
//return $view;
$pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper'); 
$pdf->loadHTML($view)->setPaper('letter', 'portrait');  
return $pdf->stream('informe.pdf');
```

Comment: Eso es jquery. Probaste hacer lo mismo con javascript?

Comment: Si obtengo el mismo resultado con javascript o jquery

Answer (score 0):

Segun entiendo, tu servidor esta respondiendo el request con el archivo PDF, es decir, con un response que tiene un header `Content-Type: application/pdf` y cuyo contenido no es HTML ni texto, sino binary, asi que no vas a poder agregarlo con `append` a un documento HTML.

Lo que podrias hacer es usar un `iframe` con el `src` que apunte a la URL que te esta generando el PDF.

Ojo que dependiendo del browser que usen tus usuarios y de la configuración que tengan en ellos, no necesariamente van a poder ver el PDF inline, sino que quiza el browser lo descargue como archivo.

Comment: Estoy pensando en que el problema puede ser con el _render()_ . Los archivos grandes o las tablas grandes pueden tardar un tiempo en renderizarse. siendo un problema de ese tipo abría una manera de controlar si se completo el renderizado antes de mandarlo a pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Para mandar una vista en dompdf lo recomendable es utilizar loadView() y para mandar html plano se utiliza loadHtml,

```
$datos = Datos::find($id);

return \PDF::loadView('pdf/informe_pdf', $datos )
        ->setPaper('letter', 'portrait')
        ->stream('informe.pdf');
```